# Named Ranges have sheet name stuck in them when sheets are copied from certain spreadsheet

Tags: function, google-sheets, spreadsheet, named-ranges

I'm merging the different versions of a D&D template and noticed that copying sheets from [a certain one](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f3x9UGTZzI8cw9BaXZPGy7Ok5jkQXTs_nNtcn_Nd038/edit?usp=sharing) of them to an existing/new spreadsheet causes the Named Range names to contain the sheet name, but in some kinda ghost form (e.g.: if trying to edit the Named Range, the name shows normally). Any clue what's causing this, how to fix it, or how to get around it?

Though I manually fixed them all by deleting and re-creating back-to-back, that version of the template might get updated in the future and I'll have to consider repeating this process.

- ["copy of WildShape" spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Y42OiZASOIyfS2OeVofPkcUvoF_rJ2VY3NTh3E1lSeE/edit?usp=sharing)
- [image - "copy of WildShape" sheet's
  Named Ranges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UqxK.png)
- [see "WildShape" sheet of merged version](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aXtu_eTl3B_8YhQf4JWmH3o-WQFT7zR3XxHaqJnnU7g/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: The named range is a reference, likely at the workbook level. Thus when you copy it, you're just duplicating the reference.

Comment: Huh, just tested it out by copying a sheet from my merged version, the main template spreadsheet, and another. I guess I just forgot all about doing it for other sheets? o.O

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Google Apps Script function to delete and re-create all named ranges (formulas using those named ranges will break because old ranges are removed)

```
function renameNRS() {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let nrs = ss.getNamedRanges();
  for (let i = 0; i < nrs.length; i++) {
    let nr = nrs[i];
    Logger.log(nr.getName());
    const range = nr.getRange();
    const oldName = nr.getName();
    const newName = oldName.replace(/'.*'!/,'');
    nr.remove();
    ss.setNamedRange(newName, range);
    Logger.log(newName);
  }
}
```

Note that ranges like `Sheet1!A:A` (without digits, dynamic range) will become `Sheet1!A1:A1000` (with digits, static range) after this